# Using basemap and matplotlib- parallels dont show up

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that plots cruise positions.

The transect plots fine however I get a error message about plotting my parallels.

Here is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_matplot.py", line 37, in <module>
    map.drawparallels(np.arange(47.5, 48.5, 1), labels=[1,0,0,0])
  File "...python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 2067, in drawparallels
    if t is not None: linecolls[int(lat)][1].append(t) 
KeyError: 47
```

Here is the code :

```
import csv
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np 


#get data from csv
lat = []
lon = []
filename = raw_input("Enter file to map: ")
with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        lat.append(row['Latitude'])
        lon.append(row['Longitude'])

lats = [float(i) for i in lat]
lons = [float(i) for i in lon]
print '.....Making map of %s.....' % filename
#draw basemap 

map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=47.5,urcrnrlat=48.5,\
            llcrnrlon=-123,urcrnrlon=-122,lat_ts=10,resolution='f')
map.fillcontinents(color='green',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='blue')

#insert data to basemap
x,y = map(lons, lats)
map.plot(x, y, 'r', marker = 'o', linestyle = '-', markersize=4)

map.drawparallels(np.arange(47.5, 48.5, 1), labels=[1,0,0,0])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-123.,-122.,.3),labels=[0,0,0,1])

plot.title(filename)
plot.show()
```

Comment: What version of Python, numpy and matplotlib are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think it's a problem with your matplotlib install.

First try updating matplotlib to the lastest version if it still does'nt work try this :

Be careful and make a backup

In :

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py
```

You must change the line :

```
if t is not None: linecolls[int(lat)][1].append(t)
```

to :

```
if t is not None: linecolls[lat][1].append(t)
```